Applying styling in bulk in QGIS
I work on many projects in QGIS where the same type of maps are created for the final reports. Each map has a particular style, and the layers always retain the same structure across projects.
Each map is a group in QGIS which I turn on when outputting the layout. To bring styles across I simply open a previous project and for each layer copy all style categories across, but it is very repetitive.
Apart from creating a pre-styled 'template' which I can save as a new project each time, is there a bulk way of copying styles across projects/maps, such as a QML file for many styles? Perhaps a plugin is available?

Save the styles as qml files, adjust the keys of the style_dict to match your layer names, and the values the paths to the style files:
style_dict =   {"index_100km":"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/index_100km_style.qml",
                "index_50km":"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/index_50km_style.qml",
                "index_10km":"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/index_10km_style.qml"}

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For all layers in layer tree
    if layer.name() in style_dict: #Check if it's in the style_dict
        stylefile = style_dict[layer.name()] #If it is, fetch the path to the style file
        processing.run("native:setlayerstyle", 
        {'INPUT':layer,'STYLE':stylefile}) #Apply the style


The same result can be accomplished using the modeler:


You can also use layer.loadNamedStyle(stylefile) instead of processing.run()

Will this work if the same layers are repeated in different groups? I have quite a few maps per project so I group them and turn each group on before outputting the layout.

I think so, have you tried and it didnt work?
